# Save all XHR requests from Chrome (or other browser) Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm working with a monolithic project which uses multiple servers to render data in a SPA.
In order to run this locally I use Mockoon to mock these requests/responses.

My problem is I have to create each response manually. This is tedious.

Does anyone have any experience with automating the process so I can just run through various screens on production and export the list of XHR requests with their respective responses which I can then import to Mockoon afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: Postman has a feature called 'intercept' which tracks all XHR requests (with patterns if needed) and saves them. You can then download the saved routes in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Mockswitch recording feature which allows to record a host  and creates automatic endpoints. You can find about the feature on their documentation site [Record responses](https://mockswitch.com)